# How to config numbering sequence separately on each branch

Tags: cloud, erp, acumatica

I am config my system has many branches. I would like to set numbering of Acumatica is generated separately for each branch. Example, in branch 1 I have sales order with nbr is 00001 after that I change to branch 2 and create Sales Order so the needed nbr is 0001.

Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 1):

It's default function of numbering sequence screen when you setup multi-branch

[image]